# How to get metadata fields of Regions/Components in a page using GraphQL?

Tags: graphql, sites-9.6

I created a GraphQL request to get all component details based on the regions of a page.

```
{
  page(namespaceId: 1, publicationId: 2, pageId: 231) {
    itemId
    title
    url
    regions {
        components {
            itemId
            multiMedia
            ... on Component {
                content { 
                    ... on UntypedContent {
                        data
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

But The response doesn't contain any metadata field information.

Is there any way to include metadata in the above query?

Comment: Good question and welcome to Tridion Stack Exchange, we're glad you joined!

Answer (score 3):

In the **UntypedContent** - will not fetch the metadata info. It just holds the page output data, the fact that in the backend metadata is stored separately, and you need to use **metadata {  metadataField }**

In Sites 9.6, instead of using **UntypedContent** you can publish using data-template-less headless publishing to use **Semantic Content Model** GraphiQL query.

Here is a sample graphiql query with metadata with the corresponding output.

```
{
  page(namespaceId: 1, publicationId: 2, pageId: 231) {
    publicationId
    itemId
    title
    regions {
      name
      components {
        itemId
        title
        ... on FinanceArticle {
          heading
          subHeading
          bodyText {
            html
          }
          numberField
          dateField
          image {
            ... on Image {
              title
              metadata {
                altText
              }
              variants {
                edges {
                  node {
                    url
                    downloadUrl
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
          metadata {
            metadataField1
            financeArticleType {
              ... on Keyword {
                title
                description
                key
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the output:

```
{
  "data": {
    "page": {
      "publicationId": 14,
      "itemId": 719,
      "title": "Finance Articles Page",
      "regions": [
        {
          "name": "Main",
          "components": [
            {
              "itemId": 718,
              "title": "Finance Article Sample 1",
              "heading": "Heading - Finance Article Sample 1",
              "subHeading": "Subheading - Finance Article Sample 1",
              "bodyText": {
                "html": "<p>Body Text content in Finance Article Sample 1.</p>"
              },
              "numberField": 11,
              "dateField": "2023-01-31T02:54:47.000",
              "image": {
                "title": "Finance Article Image 1",
                "metadata": {
                  "altText": "Alt Text - Finance Article Image 1"
                },
                "variants": {
                  "edges": [
                    {
                      "node": {
                        "url": "/media/skyline.jpg",
                        "downloadUrl": "http://localhost:8081/cd/api/binary/1/14/717"
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              },
              "metadata": {
                "metadataField1": "Metadata value!",
                "financeArticleType": {
                  "title": "Internal Report",
                  "description": "Internal Report",
                  "key": "InternalReport"
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "itemId": 720,
              "title": "Finance Article Sample 2",
              "heading": "Heading - Finance Article Sample 2",
              "subHeading": "Subheading - Finance Article Sample 2",
              "bodyText": {
                "html": "<p>Body Text content</p>\n<p>More content</p>"
              },
              "numberField": 1200,
              "dateField": "2022-12-29T02:54:47.000",
              "image": {
                "title": "Finance Article Image 2",
                "metadata": {
                  "altText": "Alt Text - Finance Article Image 2"
                },
                "variants": {
                  "edges": [
                    {
                      "node": {
                        "url": "/media/blueprint.jpg",
                        "downloadUrl": "http://localhost:8081/cd/api/binary/1/14/721"
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              },
              "metadata": {
                "metadataField1": "Metadata content",
                "financeArticleType": {
                  "title": "End of Year Announcement",
                  "description": "End of Year Announcement",
                  "key": "EndOfYearResults"
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Just in case, note that the Content Manager needs to have the Region Schema's Metadata field set to be publishable. If there is a Schema change needed, do we also need to restart the content service?

Comment: Thanks Velmurugan. We are trying to make a Get page GraphQL query request as generic one, due to page count(more than 100). Sematic content model solution won't work for us.

Comment: @AlvinReyes, The schema changes need only publishing components,  Not required for content service restart, there is a config in the content service **application.properties** to enable scm and **graphql.scm.update.interval** that needs to be managed based on customer needs.

Comment: Ah, good info. I was wondering how to get CM changes recognized in CD for Semantic Content Models!